# mongoDB: Aggregation - Is there a equivalent of the $lookup joins for the native node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

mongodb: 2.1.3

After reading about some of the [aggregation enhancements](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction) coming to mongoDB  3.2 I was excited about the "$look" pipeline stage to do left-outer equi-joins.

**Unfortunately it appears like the node driver doesn't have this operator.(I don't see it in the [native driver docs for node](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/AggregationCursor.html) and when I tried to use it I got the error:**

**Update: Here is the code I tried**

```
var cursor = db.collection('messagethreads').aggregate([
        {"$match": {
            _id: new ObjectID(threadID)}
        }, 
        {"$lookup": {
            from: "messages", 
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "threadID",
            as: "messagesList"}
        }
    ]);

    cursor.toArray(function(err,messages){
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json(error);
        }
        else if(convo === null){
            res.status(400).end();
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).json(messages);
        }
    });
});
```

Example - A ThreadMessage Document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6"), 
    name: "Messages 1"
}
```

Example - A Message Document

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630af08"), 
     "author" : "Nick", 
     "text" : "Hello", 
     "threadID" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6")
},
...
```

Intended Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6"), 
    name: "Messages 1",
    messageList:[
        {
         "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630af08"), 
         "author" : "Nick", 
         "text" : "Hello", 
         "threadID" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6")
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

**" MongoError: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup' "**

You can read more about the case for joins [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-2-of-3-worked-examples)!

**Question: Is there an intended way to perform the equivalent with the node.js native driver?**

Comment: Drivers have nothing to do with this. Aggregation pipelines are just serialized data sent to the server with no interpretation ( other than native data format to BSON conversion ), so there is nothing to support. As long as your server version supports the operation ( MongoDB 3.2 or greater ) then what you send to the server will just be executed.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I don't understand - the most recent version for the node driver is 2.1.6 https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb .I assumed it would have all the functionality of the core, but when I tried it failed and also the docs for the node native driver does show $limit to be one of the aggregate cursor methods.

Comment: Which part of *"Drivers have nothing to do with this"* is so difficult to understand? The only thing the "driver" implements is the `.aggregate()` method ( and acutally really as a wrapper over the database command that performs aggregate ). The content of a pipeline, just like any query, is just "content". There is nothing for the "driver" to do other than send it. No query or aggregation operators are within driver documentation, unless there are "helper" methods for languages that do not support dynamic structure assignments. JavaScript does.

Comment: @BlakesSeven cool, thx. Just with some of the syntactical nuances between driver implementation and the core - I figured my error could of been caused by a simple syntax adjustment.

Comment: There is "zero" syntax differences. The "pipeline" is always a "list/array" argument of objects in all driver implementations. But if you are talking about an "error" in your code you cannot resolve, then your question should show the code that is "not working for you" rather than the code that "is working" and asking *"How do I do the same thing?"*. If it's not working then clearly you are not doing the same thing.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I remember you gave me an amazing answer in the past and it helped me restructure and learn a lot. Looks like I struck a nerve today, sorry - this backend stuff can get tough. thx again!

Comment: Again, nothing to do with striking a nerve, but just trying to figure out what the question is. So, there is no difference in syntax and that is explained. Then you seem to allude to some code not working, yet you don't show the code that does not work here, if indeed it is not working. So is there a question or not? Did you really want to ask "what is the syntax for this?" when you could not have tried it to see if it worked or not, if that is the case. So just trying to work out if there is anything left to solve, or if you just did not realize how to use this.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I updated it with the code that failed for me.

Comment: Your MongoDB server version you are connecting to would appear to be a version less than MongoDB 3.2 with that specific error. `$lookup` is only a very recent addition. If you say it was working from a shell, then you must have been connecting to a different instance than your application is doing. I can show you a listing working with a 3.2.x server and 2.1.6 of the driver. Nothing special about it though.

Comment: @BlakesSeven does that mean an upgrade to the 2.1.6 driver( i got 2.1.3) will make the difference?

Comment: Again. Not the driver, it's the server. The driver does not interfere in any way and all "MongoError" messages come from the server. Also a just pinned a build to 2.1.3 of driver and it works fine. You are not connecting to a capable server that supports `$lookup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "MongoError" exception is how the driver reports any error messages from the "server", and therefor such an error indicates that the server connected to is not a version that suppport [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), being 3.2 or greater:

> *$lookup*
>
> ***New in version 3.2.***
>
> *Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing. The $lookup stage does an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined” collection.*

You can always obtain the server version you are connecting to via the [`serverStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) database command. Also in full reproducible listing:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/test",function(err,db) {

  async.series(
    [
      function(callback) {
        db.command({ "serverStatus": 1 }, function(err,status) {
          console.log(status.version);
          callback(err);
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        async.each(['threadmessage','message'],function(colname,callback) {
          db.collection(colname).remove({},callback);
        },callback);
      },

      function(callback) {
        db.collection('threadmessage').insert(
          {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6"),
            "name": "Messages 1"
          },
          callback
        );
      },

      function(callback) {
        db.collection('message').insert(
          {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630af08"),
            "author" : "Nick",
            "text" : "Hello",
            "threadID" : ObjectId("56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6")
          },
          callback
        );
      },

      function(callback) {

        var cursor = db.collection('threadmessage').aggregate([
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": "message",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "threadID",
            "as": "messagesList"
          }}
        ]);

        cursor.toArray(function(err,result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
          callback(err);
        });
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    }
  );

});
```

As well as the *package.json* with the driver version pinned, just to show there is no driver version issue:

```js
{
  "name": "lookup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "mongodb": "2.1.3"
  }
}
```

Gives the expected output with a supported server version:

```js
3.2.0
[
  {
    "_id": "56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6",
    "name": "Messages 1",
    "messagesList": [
      {
        "_id": "56b4f52c0e6368c00630af08",
        "author": "Nick",
        "text": "Hello",
        "threadID": "56b4f52c0e6368c00630aee6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So if that listing is not returning `3.2.x` on the database you are connecting to, then the `$lookup` pipeline operation is not supported here and you would have to resort to alternate means, such as pulling in the "related" information "client side" instead.

Comment: oh man! Just had the big "click"! The term "server" threw me off because I thinking of the webserver. Once people install mongoDB it's like "my database is there" and we don't think of it as a server. Haha I really had to sound like a complete noob. I checked and even though I had a GUI for 3.2.x the acutal server was 3.0.8 You are a champ! Thx a million!!